# Complete basis for space of summable monotonically decreasing sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

I'm trying to extract a response function out of some input and output data. This response function is a sequence of values $r_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$. There is a good reason why $r_n$ should be monotonically decreasing and that it is summable, meaning that the sum $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}r_i$ exists.

Now, if I have a complete basis for this space of sequences $\{b^1,b^2,b^3\dots\}$, than I can compose $(r_i)=a_1b^1+a_2b^2+\dots$ and use linear fitting on my data to find $a_i$.

I am not a mathematician and I would appreciate any help in finding a complete basis for space of monotonically decreasing summable sequences. How does one know that the basis is complete? My naive guess was a basis $b^k=(e^{-ki})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Is this basis complete?

**Edit**: For clarification, components $a_i$ are nonnegative. If this addition makes this space something else than vector space (module maybe), is that problematic for existence of basis?

Comment: What's the point of downvoting a new user and not leaving a comment to suggest why?

Comment: You tagged your question vector-spaces, but note that the set of monotonically decreasing functions is not a vector space since for example additive inverses do not exist. In particular, the concept of basis is to be defined by you in this context. Just saying that every monotonically decreasing sequence can be written uniquely as $\sum_i a_i b^i$ seems to be not enough in this context as you might also have to explain which $a_i$ you want to be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me explain the difference of a vector space and what you are considering by giving an example which is related to your set of sequences.

The set $c$ of convergent sequences is a vector space (or a module) over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, that is, we have an addition (which is defined by $(x_n)_n + (y_n)_n = (x_n + y_n)$ for $(x_n)_n$, $(y_n)_n \in c$) and a scalar multiplication (which is defined by $\lambda (x_n)_n = (\lambda x_n)_n$ for $(x_n)_n \in c$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$) and these satisfy certain properties, for example, $+$ is associative, commutative, the sequence which is constant $0$ is a neutral element for $+$ and for every sequence $x$ there exists $y$ with $x + y = 0$.

Note also that in a vector space you only can take finite sums. You need a concept of convergence to talk about infinite sums. In the case of $c$, we can define a norm $\| \cdot \|$ by setting $$\|x\| = \sup\{x_n \:|\: n \geq 1\}$$ and then we can say that a sequence $(x(n))_n$ of sequences $x(n)$ converges to a sequence $x$ if and only of $\|x(n) - x\| \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

This way $c$ becomes a normed vector space and we can talk define a basis of $c$ to be a set $\{b^1, b^2, \dots\}$ such that every element $x \in c$ can be (uniquely) written as $x = \sum_{i}^{\infty} a_i b^i$ where the $a_i$ are real numbers and the infinite sum means that $x$ is the limit of the sequence of sequences $(\sum_{i = 1}^N a_i b^i)_{N}$.
An example of such a basis is given by $\{e_1, e_2, \dots\}$ where $e_k$ is 
has $1$ as its $k$th entry and is $0$ everywhere else. In fact every $x \in c$ can be written as $x = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k e_k$.

On the other hand let us consider the set $m$ of monotonically decreasing sequences $x$ for which $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k$ exists. This last condition implies that $m$ is a subset of $c$ and one sees easily that the addition of two sequences in $m$ again gives a sequence in $m$. However, the additive inverse of a non-zero element in $m$ is not in $m$. Also the scalar multiple $\lambda x$ of a non-zero element $x \in m$ is only in $m$ if $\lambda$ is non-negative. Thus we do not have a vector space structure on $m$.

Still, we can add in $m$, we can take non-negative multiples and we can use the norm $\|\cdot\|$ to make sense out of infinite sums. We can now define a 'basis' for $m$ to be a set $\{b^1,b^2,\dots\}$ of elements of $m$ such that every $x \in m$ has can be (uniquely) written as $x = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i b^i$ where the $a_i$ are now positive real numbers.

Let us show that such a 'basis' exists.

The sequence $E_N = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} e_k$ is the sequence which has a $1$ in the first $N$ entries and $0$ everywhere else. In particular $E_N$ is an element of $m$.
Note that we have $e_N = E_N - E_{N-1}$ for $N > 1$ and $e_1 = E_1$.
Let us show that $\{E_1, E_2, \dots\}$ is a 'basis' for $m$.

Let $x = (x_k)_{k} \in m$. Note that we have 
\begin{align} x = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k e_k &= x_1 E_1 + \sum_{k = 2}^\infty x_k (E_k - E_{k-1}) \\ &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k E_k - \sum_{k = 2}^\infty x_{k} E_{k-1} \\ &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k E_k - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_{k + 1} E_{k}  = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (x_k - x_{k + 1}) E_k
\end{align}
For the third equality sign we have to make sure that the infinite sums $\sum_{k = 1}^N x_k E_k$  and $\sum_{k = 1}^N x_k E_{k-1}$ make sense. However, we have  $$\sum_{k = 1}^N x_k E_k  = \sum_{k = 1}^N x_k \sum_{l = 1}^k e_l = \sum_{l = 1}^N (\sum_{k = l}^N x_k) e_l$$
And thus for $N \to \infty$ we obtain that $\sum_{k = 1}^N x_k E_k$ converges to the sequence $(\sum_{n = k}^\infty x_n)_k$. A similar calculation shows that $\sum_{k = 2}^\infty x_{k} E_{k -1}$ makes sense.

As we see now from the first calculation, $x$ can be written as a non-negative linear combination of the $E_k$ (by assumption $x_k - x_{k+1}$ is non-negative), so $\{E_1, E_2, \dots, \}$ is a 'basis' of the desired form.

Note that $b^{k} = \{e^{-ki}\}_i$ does not work, since for example the $E_k$ cannot be represented as a nonnegative linear combination of these sequences. In fact, it is quite easy to see that any 'basis' has to consist of sequences which become $0$ eventually.